# Finding the source of a HTTP_COOKIE in a response payload?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

The following code correctly identifies a properly formed payload and sends a 200 response.

```
if($signature == $authKey)
{
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
        $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
        foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
            $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
            $name = trim($parts[0]);
            setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
            setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
        }
    }
    http_response_code(200);
    XeroWebHookHandler::handlePayload($rawPayload);
}
```

The endpoint however, won't accept a HTTP response containing a cookie.

The above code is giving me the following response `Response contained a cookie`.

My service is hosted on an AWS EC2 instance running a standard Ubuntu server hosting apache.

What methods can I use to correctly identify what might be setting a `HTTP_COOKIE` variable.  Alternatively, am I clearing it correctly?

Comment: The bulk of cookie control is still in the realm of the browser. I don't think you're going to be able to locate a "source" of the cookie from PHP. `array_keys($_COOKIE)` is the easiest way to get the cookie names, rather than manually processing `$_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']`

Comment: Ok.  So this is a HTTP response to a web hook request -there is no browser.  Can you offer any advice?  Something is either modifying the $_SERVER variable in `http_response_code()', or perhaps AWS is adding a cookie to the response payload on the way out.  Or something else I haven't thought of.

Comment: Is it possible for you to manually create the request in something like [PostMan](https://www.getpostman.com/)? You may get more insight into the response payload.

Comment: I've been using "Advanced REST client" and I can't see anything. This is slightly frustrating, but that's the job :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. The answer helped in my specific case, but I will share it in case anyone else has the same issue.

Session cookies are the issue.

```
session_destroy();
setcookie("PHPSESSID", "", time()-3600, "/");
```

I found that `session_destroy()` alone left some crumbs.